# How do I redirect User and stop reentry of data on refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a form that users will fill then submit. On the action page, I want to insert the data and display a success message but not on the action page because when I refresh the page, I get warnings of empty fields like (Warning: Undefined array key "email" in......) and in the database  a raw with some empty columns is inserted) What I would like is how to display the success message [Must]. Is there a way I can show the success message may be in a dialog box in the index page or any way that a user cannot refresh the action page and reenter the data?

```html
 <form action="process.php" method="post" >
User Name:  
<input  type="text" name="username" >
User Email
<input  type="text" name="useremail" >
Date of birth
<input  type="date" name="dob">
Request:  
<input  type="text" name="request" >
<input type="submit"  name="submit" >
</form>      


<!--this is the action Page-->

    <?php
$user= $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['useremail'];
$dob= $_POST['dob'];
$request= $_POST['request'];

$servername = "localhost";
// Enter your MySQL username below(default=root)
$username = "root";
// Enter your MySQL password below
$password = "";
$dbname = "Test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    header("location:connection_error.php?error=$conn->connect_error");
    die($conn->connect_error);
}
 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (username, useremail, dob, request) VALUES ('$user','$email','$dob','$request');

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
  
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

exit;
?>







<!--So I would like to redirect the user to index page or any other page and display some sort of cancelable notification like this -->

     <p> Your application was submited, your application number is <?php echo " " . $last_id; ?></p><br>  <p> You will be contacted via your email <?php echo $_POST['email-owner']; ?> </p>    <button>close and go back OK</button>
```

Comment: You could just use conditionals like if empty()

Comment: @KevinGales Thanks for the info. I am new to PHP. do you h ave like an example you can refer me to. I dont know how to go about the if empty condition.

Comment: like if(empty($user) || empty($email) ||.......){ echo "error one of the fields is empty" } else {  //your code to insert the data }

Comment: @KevinGales  This is very clear for me as a bigineer. Thanks, bro. Imma try it out.

Comment: Do so then if you have other problems,ask..